# What is the "maybe" caller id suggestion in the call log based on?

Tags: iphone, caller-id

I got a call from a phone number that is not stored in my address book, and in the call log, under the number, a name was suggested: "Maybe: X" (where X is the guessed name).

Where is this guess coming from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

iOS scans your email for contact info.  If the phone number is not in your *Address Book*, for matches, it looks to your email to see if anyone with this number sent you email.  If it finds the phone number associated with a contact from your email, it will show you "Maybe:" with its guess of the person's name.

You can disable this feature, if you want, by:

1. Go to *Settings --> Mail, Contacts, Calendars*
2. Under *Contacts*, toggle the switch labeled *Contacts Found in Mail* to the *OFF* position

Comment: If I search macOS Mail app for the last four digits of the phone number, I get zero results.

Answer (score 7):

This is part of the Proactivity features new with iOS 9. It looks at info in emails to make an educated guess at who's calling.

On [this Apple page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918130539/http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#gallery-siri-assistant-view-contacts), the new feature is shown and described.

> [image: iPhone with Maybe: John Appleseed in calling interface under phone number]
>
> **Who’s calling?**
>
> Incoming call from an unknown number? If that number appeared in an email, iOS 9 lets you know who might be calling. And if someone sends you an email with contact information, the details can automatically be added to Contacts.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a bug in iOS 11.2 that can result in "Maybe" being displayed even when "Find Contacts in Other Apps" is disabled (equivalent of iOS 10 "Contacts Found in Mail".

I turned iMessage off on my 11.2 device. Then I reenabled it. After doing that most, but not all, of my messages display with the Maybe: prefix even with "Find Contacts in Other Apps" disabled.

I've seen bugs with Spotlight and Contacts in iOS with large number of Contacts. I think this might be related.

So if you are using 11.2 you may need to wait for a bug fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn off this feature:
For iOS 10 > go to settings > contacts > Contacts found in Apps > turn off

Answer (score 0):

Every other answer here is suggesting the name is pulled from an automatic search of Mail app. I searched Mail app and found no correlation.

But then I noticed at one point the text message mentions the suggested name. So in my case, it pulled the name from the content of text message's history.

Answer (score -2):

1. Settings
2. General
3. Messaging
4. Turn on group messages.

Then :

1. Settings
2. General
3. Reset
4. Reset network settings

then delete the thread that was causing issues and restart conversation

Comment: This question is about the call log, not conversations in Messages.